# Asp.net IE & Safari JQuery compatiblity issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I recently developed a site but I am having some troubles with displaying a particular JQuery Carousel on Safari be it on the PC or iPhone. Displaying on IE or Firefox has no problem. The issue arise when I refresh that particular page, the JQuery becomes distorted, the image is sliced and buttons gone. I would really like to show some code but I am not sure where to pinpoint the problem.

This is the page:

http://clotheher.com.microsoft2008hosting.com/ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId=2&&CategoryId=1

On the bottom right side is the carousel. Anyone experiences such problem or understand this behavior please kindly let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be jQuery, but rather CSS.

`div.caroufredsel_wrapper` and `ul#foo2` both have specified heights which are causing the images/buttons to cutoff.